# How to draw images to viewport in Max SDK

Tags: sdk, 3d, max, 3dsmax

I want to be able to draw images to the viewport in my 3d Max Plugin,
The GraphicsWindow Class has functions for drawing 3d objects in the viewport but these drawing calls are limited by the current viewport and graphics render limits.
This is undesirable as the image I want to draw should always be drawn no matter what graphics mode 3d max is in and or hardware is used, futher i am only drawing 2d images so there is no need to draw it in a 3d context.

I have managed to get the HWND of the viewport and the max sdk has the function
DrawIconButton();

and i have tried using this function but it does not function properly, the image flickers randomly with user interaction, but disappears when there is no interactivity.
i Have implemented this function in the
RedrawViewsCallback function, however the DrawIconButton() function is not documented and i am not sure if this is the correct way to implemented it.

Here is the code i am using to draw the image:

```
void Sketch_RedrawViewsCallback::proc (Interface * ip)
{

    Interface10* ip10 = GetCOREInterface10();
    ViewExp* viewExp = ip10->GetActiveViewport();
    ViewExp10* currentViewport;

    if (viewExp != NULL)
    {
        currentViewport = reinterpret_cast<ViewExp10*>(viewExp->Execute(ViewExp::kEXECUTE_GET_VIEWEXP_10));
    } else {
        return;
    }

    GraphicsWindow* gw = currentViewport->getGW();

    HWND ViewportWindow = gw->getHWnd();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(ViewportWindow); 
    HBITMAP bitmapImage = LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
    Rect rbox(IPoint2(0,0),IPoint2(48,48));

    DrawIconButton(hdc, bitmapImage, rbox, rbox, true);

    ReleaseDC(ViewportWindow, hdc);
    ip->ReleaseViewport(currentViewport);

};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code you've tried so far that isn't working as you'd expect. If no one knows what you're trying to do, it's pretty hard to help you figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to draw directly to the view-port window, however I have solved the problem by using a transparent modeless dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

May be a complete redraw will solve the issue. [ForceCompleteRedraw](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/index.html?url=cpp_ref/class_interface.html,topicNumber=cpp_ref_class_interface_html6c3c270e-1b26-42d7-8048-19c1b5940a6a,hash=a4f0db23d120f4463676c54a1865190e4)